# EF Inserting Duplicate Parent Objects

Tags: entity-framework

I have two classes:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int FooId {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Bar> Bars {get;set;}
}

public class Bar
{
    public int BarId {get;set;}
    public virtual Foo {get;set;}
}
```

If I run the following code, I get a `Foreign Key Conflict` on FooId.

```
var foo = from f in context.Foos
          where f.FooId == 1
          select f;

var bar = new Bar();
bar.Foo = foo;

context.Bars.Add(bar);
context.SaveChanges();
```

If I disable all the key checks in SQL, I end up with a duplicate `Foo` in the database.

Comment: What version of Entity Framework? 4.0 code first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading the `foo` with the **same context** as adding the new `bar` with the related `foo` won't cause a duplication. My guess is that your real code uses two different contexts.

The only thing to change in the code (which won't compile because `foo` is an `IQueryable<Foo>` and not a `Foo`) is to materialize the `foo`, for example:

```
var foo = (from f in context.Foos
          where f.FooId == 1
          select f).Single();
```

Other than that the code snippet is fine.

Comment: Yeah, I was using DI, the content instance was being generated from scratch each time. #numpty

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are approaching the problem in the wrong way. You want to add the new Bar object to your existing foo object instead of the other way round:

```
var foo = from f in context.Foos
          where f.FooId == 1
          select f;

var bar = new Bar();
foo.Bars.Add(bar);

context.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var bar = new Bar();
context.Bars.Add(bar);
bar.Foo == foo;
context.SaveChanges();
```

It seems like the entity key isn't being set uniquely when assignment occurs before the entity is added to the context.

Comment: I'm now getting `Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Bar' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF`

Comment: @mattdwen is there a problem with turning IDENTITY_INSERT ON?

Comment: Yes, because the ID is being auto generated by the DB.  If I set `IDENTITY_INSERT ON`, the ID is inserted as `0`.

Comment: I am having this same issue...anyone find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best practice, but when I ran into this issue I ended up setting the parent entity to Null but maintain any FK reference, this stopped the parent entity from being inserted on child entities:

```
var bar = new Bar();
context.Bars.Add(bar);
bar.Foo == null;
bar.FooId = existingFooParent.Id;
context.SaveChanges();
```