# Duplicate row in associated entity using entity frameworks with POCO entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, poco, entity-relationship

I' m having a problem using `Entity-Frameworks` with `POCO` entities. I Have a relation between product and category, I have the following code to persist in database:

```
    public virtual void Add(T entity)
    {
        ContextEntity.AddObject(entity);
        Context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

I' m trying to create a new Product with already existent category, but when I query the database, the new product have a relation with a new category with the same values than the previous category that I'm triying to asociate.
I have been searched for the answer, but the examples doesn't work with me, because I dont have the same methods that they use in the example. Maybe because I'm using `POCO` entities, I'm not sure.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5035804/ef-inserting-duplicate-parent-objects, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5823115/adding-user-to-a-role-inserts-a-duplicate-user-into-users-table

Answer (score 1):

I've made a few assumptions about your code but maybe one of these methods will help.

1. When creating the new Product instance you can set the foreign key
   value like CategoryId to the existing Category Id
2. If you want to set the navigation property "Product.Category" you
       must make sure of the following:

The referenced Category instance must be owned by the context by either using the `Context.Categories.Attach` or by first fetching it through the context with e.g. `Context.Categories.FirstOrDefault(c => c.id == 1)`

If you set `Product.Category` equal to a disconnected instance of Category the context will automatically try and add the referenced instance.

Comment: I'm getting an instance of Category using something like context.Categories.FirstOrDefault(c => c.id == 1) But the frameworks is inserting a new row anyway. note: I'm using reference to objects, no CategoryId to fill the relation

Comment: You must use the same context instance you retrieved the Category with when you add the product.  If it's a different context instance you have to attach the Category to the new context.  If you are using the same context instance then could you post some more code here so we can check it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(CategoriaView collection)
    {
        try
        {
            UnidadDeMedida unidadDeMedida= 
                unidadDeMedidaService.GetByCriteria(i => i.IdUnidadDeMedida == collection.UnidadDeMedida.IdUnidadDeMedida)
                .FirstOrDefault();
            Mapper.CreateMap<UnidadDeMedida,UnidadDeMedidaView>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<UnidadDeMedidaView,UnidadDeMedida>();
            UnidadDeMedidaView unidadDeMedidaView =
                Mapper.Map<UnidadDeMedida,UnidadDeMedidaView>(unidadDeMedida);
            collection.UnidadDeMedida = unidadDeMedidaView;
            Mapper.CreateMap<CategoriaView, Categoria>();

            Categoria categoria =
                Mapper.Map<CategoriaView, Categoria>(collection);
            categoria.UnidadDeMedida = unidadDeMedida;
            service.Add(categoria);

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this an answer or an addition to your question?