# Entity Framework - Virtual Property is inserting data in respective table

Tags: entity-framework

Not sure about title of the question, anyways! I have my Model Class `RandomStuff` which has `Environment` as Virtual Property.

```
public class RandomStuff
    {
        //NOT SHOWN ON FORM HIDDEN JUST TO MAKE IT EASIER IN DB
        [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty]
        public int JobId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [ForeignKey("Environment")]
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty]
        [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
        public int EnvironmentId { get; set; }

        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty ]
        public virtual Environment Environment { get; set; }
}
```

My Environment is as below:-

```
[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonObject(Newtonsoft.Json.MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
    [DataContract]
    public class Environment
    {
        [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty]
        [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

    }
```

Now, in my controller I have :-

```
public HttpResponseMessage Save(RandomStuff stuff)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //Some stuff here
                db.RandomStuffs.Add(stuff);//When this excutes, it is 
                                           //inserting data in Environment table also.
                db.SaveChanges();


            }
        }
```

Now, whenever i am adding stuff to my `RandomStuff` table, it is adding Environment also.

**EDIT:**

I'll try to explain with general example, which I took from [ef-inserting-duplicate-parent-objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5035804/ef-inserting-duplicate-parent-objects)

```
public class Foo
{
    public int FooId {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Bar> Bars {get;set;}
}

public class Bar
{
    public int BarId {get;set;}
    public strung BarName {get;set;}
}
```

Now, if above being my model structure. I am trying to add one Foo data to my DB.

```
db.Foo.Add(new Foo{
                FooId=1, 
                Bars=new List<Bar>(){
                    new Bar{
                        BarId=2, 
                        BarName="Something"
                    }
                }
            })//Something of this sort will be my data, which needs to be inserted
          //Now this record "new Bar{BarId=2, BarName="Something"}" is already present in DB
```

Now, what is happening is, it is inserting data in Foo table with id=1 and it is also adding duplicate in Bars table with id 2.

Also if I use something like below, my requirement is fulfilled:

```
db.Entry(fooModelDataComingFromSomewhere.Bars).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
```

Comment: Please would u mind replying with `reasons` for down vote. :(

Comment: is your question related to Entity Framework creating duplicate inserts of your related entities?

Comment: @AndrewCounts- after your comment, I just googled around with what you actually meant by `Entity Framework creating duplicate inserts of your related entities`, I found an easier way to explain my issue. Please see the Edit of my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question still isn't quite clear, as you are now providing code snippets from another post that aren't even in the same structure as the code you are having an issue with.  However, I'm still guessing that your issue is with duplicate inserts, so I'll try to provide a suggestion.

When you use the `Add()` Method on the Entity Framework DB Context, it marks the **entire graph** of connected objects as **Added**, even if the item already exists in the database.  A common situation that you are probably seeing is that when you Add an object of type `RandomStuff` it is also adding a new object of type `Environment`, and though `Environment.Name` is the same, `Environment.Id` is Database assigned, and since Entity Framework has marked the entire graph as Added, it creates a new Environment object, with the same `Name` but a new `Id`.  therefore, you have multiple `Environment` rows in your table with the same `Name`.

The solution is deceptively simple.  Since you already have a Property on your `RandomStuff` object to hold the Foreign Key representing the `Environment` object, instead of adding a new `Environment` object to the graph, simply create your `RandomStuff` object and add the value of the `EnvironmentId`.  In other words,

Instead of creating a new `RandomStuff` Object this way:

```
var RandomStuff randomStuff = new RandomStuff {
                                     Environment = new Environment {
                                                    Name = "Existing Environment"
                                                     }
                                     }
```

create it like this:

```
var RandomStuff randomStuff = new RandomStuff {
                                     EnvironmentId = existingEnvironment.Id
                                    }
```